# How to use Reddit's POST api?

Tags: php, post, reddit

I have managed to grab data from Reddit easily, displaying all links that users have submitted to a sub-reddit. What I want to achieve now though is to allow users of my site to login to reddit, and post to that sub-reddit from my site.

How would I achieve this using PHP?

I have searched the web everywhere and cannot seem to find anything that can help me. I am a begginer a PHP so it's quite confusing at times.

If there is an article explaining exactly what I want, I would be grateful if you could link me to it :)

Thank you!

EDIT: Documentation here; http://www.reddit.com/dev/api

Comment: Where is the documentation for this API?

Comment: here http://www.reddit.com/dev/api

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment to use/look into this opensource project on [github](https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk) (not my project). It uses curl to communicate and it might even be enough for you.

Another option would be to look into [httpRequest::send](http://www.php.net//manual/en/httprequest.send.php) and simply send your post variables with this method. This is if you like things to be more lowlevel.

The reddit api basically tells you what post parameters you need for which action